# Is $\Lambda:X\longrightarrow\mathbb K$ continuous if $\{\Lambda(x_k)\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded when $x_k \longrightarrow0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $X$ a normed space over $\mathbb K$ ($=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) and $\Lambda:X\longrightarrow\mathbb K$ a linear aplication.

Prove that if $\{\Lambda(x_k)\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded $\forall(x_k)\subset X$ such that $x_k \longrightarrow0$, then $\Lambda$ is continuous.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have been thinking about the property of linear aplications in normed spaces which affirms that a linear operator is continous iif it is bounded but I have not been able to reach any conclusion.

Comment: Take $x_k \to 0$ and show that $\Lambda x_k \to 0$ by applying the hypothesis to $c_kx_k$ with $c_k$'s suitably chosen. (Make $c_k$ dependent on $\|x_k\|$).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I dont see your point

Comment: This looks very much like a homework problem.  You did not show your attempt and did not even try to use any of my hints. It is against the site's rules to answer such a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\Lambda:X\longrightarrow\mathbb K$ is not continuous. Then $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$ , $\exists (x_n) \in X$ such that $|\Lambda(x_n) |>n^2\|x_n\|$

Then $|\Lambda(\frac{x_n}{n\|x_n\|})|>n$

The the sequence $(y_n)\subset X$ where $y_n=\frac{x_n}{n\|x_n\|}\to 0 $ in $(X, \|•\|) $.

But the set $\{\Lambda(y_n)\}$ is not bounded. This is a contradiction.

Hence $\Lambda:X\longrightarrow\mathbb K$ is  continuous.

Comment: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sir. Is my solution correct? I will delete my answer.

Comment: It is correct. You cannot delete the answer when there is an approval.